# Starting a .bat with a service

Tags: windows, windows-services

I have a .bat file I want to start every time windows loads.  Is there a cheap way of having a service (or something else, I don't care what) launch this .bat file?  Preferably I do not want the user to see any of this happening.

Thanks.

Comment: I second @avanek's recommendation for using the Task Scheduler, but if you really want to write a Windows service to do this you could use the `Process` class to launch your .bat with `proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use the Windows [Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) personally.

Edit:

The above link is primarily for the API. Here's a link for using the [Task Scheduler 2.0 GUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756979.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a service... Just place it in the users `Startup` folder or use the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` entry in the registry.